# No diffs from pytest AssertionErrors when straying from common test file name scheme

Tags: pytest, hy

I have the following `conftest.py` for a `pytest` plugin for `hy`, adapted from the [official `hy` conftest](https://github.com/hylang/hy/blob/master/conftest.py), but AssertionErros are not diffed for files beginning with `test-`, only `test_`, even when using `-vv` on the command line.

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path

import pytest

import hy

NATIVE_TESTS = Path.cwd().joinpath("tests", "native_tests")

# https://github.com/hylang/hy/issues/2029
os.environ.pop("HYSTARTUP", None)


def pytest_collect_file(parent, path):
    if (
        path.ext in (".hy", ".py")
        and (
            path.basename.startswith("test_")
            or path.basename.startswith("test-")
            or path.basename.endswith("_test")
            or path.basename.endswith("-test")
        )
        # Mimics https://github.com/hylang/hy/blob/master/conftest.py#L38:
        and (
            (not NATIVE_TESTS.exists())
            or (
                NATIVE_TESTS.exists() and (str(NATIVE_TESTS) in (path.dirname + os.sep))
            )
        )
        and path.basename != "__init__.hy"
    ):
        path = Path(path)
        path.touch(exist_ok=True)
        return pytest.Module.from_parent(parent, path=path)
```

I have the following `__init__.py` as well, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```py
import pytest

pytest.register_assert_rewrite("pytest_hy")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mangling applies to names in Hy code, not file names. So if you have a file named `foo_bar.hy`, you can import it as `(import foo-bar)`, but calling your file `foo-bar.hy` is not really supported in any fashion by Hy's import system, let alone by pytest. In particular, `(import foo-bar)` will look for `foo_bar.hy`, as just mentioned, not `foo-bar.hy`.

Comment: But the conftest picks up these files and runs them anyway; its just the AssertionError diffs that aren't working.

Comment: @ShadowRylander I'm surprised it gets that close to working, but it's still not intentionally supported. If you want to make this work, you may need to edit the guts of both pytest and Hy. I'd recommend just using underscores in your file names, though.

Comment: Will do, but did you not write the original conftest? I adapted it from yours and [this plugin here](https://github.com/arjaz/pytest-hylang).

Comment: @ShadowRylander I did, yeah: https://github.com/hylang/hy/commits/master/conftest.py I never tried to support file names with hyphens, though. In Hy's `setup.cfg` you can see how I set `python_functions` to compensate for mangling of function names, as opposed to file names.

Comment: You might find Hyrule's `conftest.py` enlightening. It's a little simpler.